# How to open the dropdown when clicking on the select button in Jodit?

Tags: javascript, jodit

I am using the Jodit editor in my React application.
Now I need a custom button in the Toolbar to insert text-snippets into the editor.
This works all fine.

I got a Button with a custom Icon and on its right side there is a chevron that opens and collapses my dropdown.

The thing I can't figure out is, how can I make my custom button more like the standard paragraph button. The paragraph button also has the chevron but it doesn't matter where it is clicked, it always opens the dropdown.

So my extraButton-Config contains this:

```
{
  name: "Textbausteine",
  icon: "dots",
  list: textModules.map((module) => module.name),
  tooltip: "Textbaustein einfügen",
  exec: (
    jodit: IJodit,
    _current: Nullable<Node>,
    options: {
      button: IToolbarButton;
      control: IControlType<IJodit>;
      originalEvent: Event;
    },
  ) => {

    if (options.control.args) {
      const moduleIndex = options.control.args?.at(1);
      jodit.selection.insertHTML(textModules[moduleIndex].content);
    }
      else {
        // open dropdown
    }
  },
}
```

I tried `jodit.selection.expandSelection()` but nothing happens.

Anyone know how I can open a dropdown in the toolbar?

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for how to solve the problem, there it is necessary to **return false** if it did not find the arguments

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).